# Does the orthocenter have any special properties?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Each of the commonly known triangle centers I know has some sort of special property. For example:

- The incenter is the center of the inscribed circle.
- The circumcenter is the center of the circle defined by three points.
- The centroid is the gravitational center of an object.

Does the orthocenter have any similar property? How about the symmedian center or the nine-point center?

Comment: So do you mean properties which are not directly geometric?

Comment: I suppose that would work.

Comment: Then a Google search should work, and sites like Mathworld or Wikipedia and their sources might help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Euler line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line) or [Euler circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle), and these are just examples. There are numerous properties in the triangle, many involving the orthocenter. And there are litterally hundreds of *special points*.
Some even say it's a sin to spend too much time looking for such properties. :-)

Comment: Please take a look on the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321816/proving-lines-are-perpendicular

Answer (score 0):

Take [isogonal conjugate](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Isogonal_conjugate) of orthocenter and you get the circumcenter of that triangle.

Answer (score 0):

When constructing the orthocenter or triangle `T`, the 3 feet of the altitudes can be connected to form what is called the orthic triangle, `t`. When `T` is acute, the orthocenter is the incenter of the incircle of `t` while the vertices of `T` are the excenters of the excircles of `t`. When the triangle is obtuse then the roles of the vertex of the obtuse angle and the orthocenter are reversed.